# Deletion of Dynamically Allocated Memory

Tags: c++

I have been given a task, where I need to create the string_copy function Note that the function body and prototypes have been given by the source and that needs to be maintained. The portions written by me are after the comment `write your code here`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int string_length(const char* string_c);
char* string_copy(const char* string_c);

int main()
{
    const char* string_c = "This is a string and is a long one so that we can create memory leaks when it is copied and not deleted";

    // write your code here
    int length = string_length(string_c);
    cout << "Copied String: " << string_copy(string_c) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int string_length(const char* string) {
    int length = 0;
    for (const char* ptr = string; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) {
        ++length;
    }
    return length;
}

char* string_copy(const char* string) {
    // we need to add 1 because of ’\0’
    char* result = new char[string_length(string) + 1];

    // write your code here (remember zero-termination !)
    int i;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = string[i];
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Now task tells me

> that it is very important that any memory allocated with e=new TYPE is
>   released later with delete e (and a=new TYPE[size] with delete [] a)
>   else this will lead to an error.

It is not exactly clear if error means `compile/runtime error` or error as in my task did not meet the requirement error.

My question is, in this code how do I delete the intermediate dynamically created `result` array? If I delete `result`, won't it fail the purpose of the task? Then how am I to respect the quotation above or maybe simulate memory leak as given in the `long` string constant?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Why the negative votes? Please at least explain the reason! I am not asking any solution or something, but mere suggestion if I am missing some point or not!

Comment: There's no hate in the negative votes. They're simply marking that this question is not useful for future users of the site. Having just looked at your question: there are may similar questions already. If you simply read the Q&A on related questions you may be able to get your own answer. Unfortunately not everyone is willing to take the time to offer constructive criticism.

Comment: @CraigYoung  I think the technical part of the question may have similar questions already but in my case I wanted to understand the expectation of the task (in the question) from me (as I presumed I may not know the task's intent as I am not well versed in the language), not exactly the technical solution. I think I fairly understand the Q&A and have read it more than once, I would rather say the negative votes conform to a general elitist mindset discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Comment: I can't speak for the down-voters. But it is clear to me that your question is useful to only an extremely narrow audience. Unfortunately the task you were assigned makes your question somewhat contrived. This is exacerbated by the task details not using correct terminology. There's a huge difference between "lead to an error" and "lead to a memory leak".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller of `string_copy` would be responsible for releasing the memory when it's done with it by calling `delete[]` on it.

This is, by the way, a terrible way to write C++ code. You should be using `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` or something like that.

Here's why:

```
int length = string_length(string_c);
char* copy = string_copy(string_c);
cout << "Copied String: " << copy << endl;
delete[] copy;
return 0;
```

Yuck.

Comment: True! This is a task and I have no control on how it is presented to me. Now I know what exactly the question meant. Transiting from `C#` is so tough :(

Comment: @Jeet.Deir No. I'd say transitioning out of C# but being forced to use ***old*** style C++ techniques makes it _unnecessarily_ tough.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the ideal solution is to use `std::string` and not `char *`. There is no real need of `using char *` instead of `std::string` in your example.
With `std::string`:

- You don't need to new anything
- You don't need to delete anything
- You can do everything with std::string, that you do with char *.

Comment: True! But this is a task presented to me and I really have no control on how I need to execute it!